# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
function updateAnalysers(id) {

    var canvas = document.getElementById(id);

    canvasWidth = canvas.width;    
    canvasHeight = canvas.height;
    analyserContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

    {
        var fils = Math.round(canvasWidth / 3);
        var byts = new Uint8Array(analyserNode.frequencyBinCount);

        analyserNode.getByteFrequencyData(byts); 

        analyserContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        analyserContext.fillStyle = 'GRAY';
        analyserContext.lineCap = 'round';

        var multiplier = analyserNode.frequencyBinCount / fils;

        for (var i = 0; i < fils; ++i) {
            var magnitude = 0;
            var offset = Math.floor( i * multiplier );

            for (var j = 0; j< multiplier; j++)
                magnitude += byts[offset + j];
                magnitude = (magnitude / multiplier) + 2;

            analyserContext.fillRect(i * 3, canvasHeight, 1, -magnitude);
        }
    }

    rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame( updateAnalysers("analyser") );
}
```

O erro ocorre nesta última linha:

```
rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame( updateAnalysers("analyser") );
```

Como corrigilo?

Comment: Essa função está a chamar-se a sí própria em loop, daí o erro....

Comment: Ora pois, ela não deveria fazer isto, começou a fazer isto quando eu coloquei-a o parametro "analyser", @Sergio

Comment: @Sergio quando eu a deixo apenas assim: `rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame( updateAnalysers );` funciona que é uma beleza

Comment: Tente substituir rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame( updateAnalysers("analyser") );  por     rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame( updateAnalysers(id) );

Comment: Funciona porque estás a passar a função para ser corrida dentro da outra função, quando corres a função dentro de sí própria dá erro.

Comment: @Sergio então não tem como eu passar a variavel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro é porque você está chamando a função dentro dela própria, infinitas vezes, aqui:

```
rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame( updateAnalysers("analyser") );
```

Na verdade o `requestAnimationFrame` espera receber uma referência para uma função, mas em vez de passar uma referência você está invocando a função. Passar a referência seria assim:

```
rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame( updateAnalysers );
```

Porém nesse caso você deixaria de passar o parâmetro. Para passar com o parâmetro engessado, você pode fazer um [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
var funcaoDeUpdate = updateAnalysers.bind(null, id);
rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame( funcaoDeUpdate );
```