# Estou tentando fazer um programa que mostre a tabuada que o usuário escolher, porém está compilando apenas a primeira multiplicação. (x * 1 = x)

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var mT = parseInt(prompt("A tabuada de qual numero deseja ver?(preencha somente com o numero.)"));

var n = 1;

function mostra(frase) {
  document.write(frase);
  pL();
};

function pL() {
  mostra("<br>" + "<hr>" + "<br>");
};

while (n <= 10) {
  mostra(mT + " * " + n + " = " + mT * n);
  n = n + 1;
};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body bgcolor=000000 text=FF0000>
  <script>
    console.log("apenas para o body :)");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Seu erro está aqui, ao chamar a funcão `pL`:

```
function mostra(frase) {
  document.write(frase);
  pL(); // esse chamada ativa a recursão infinita....
};
```

Essa chamada `pL` chama novamente a funcão `mostra` e esta internamente chama a funcão `pL` que chama novamente `mostra` e por ai vai... e isso gera uma recursão infinita, o que vai gerar o erro:

> "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

O jeito mais simples para o seu caso seria ignorar essa funcão `pL` e trabalhar somente com `mostra`, e nos parâmetros você passaria um `<br>` e o `<hr>`

```js
var mT = parseInt(prompt("A tabuada de qual numero deseja ver?(preencha somente com o numero.)"));

var n = 1;

function mostra(frase) {
  document.write(frase);
};

while (n <= 10) {
  mostra(mT + " * " + n + " = " + mT * n + '<br><hr>'); // passa '<br><hr>' aqui para quebrar a linha
  n = n + 1;
};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body bgcolor=000000 text=FF0000>
  <script>
    console.log("apenas para o body :)");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Perguntas que falam sobre o erro gerado por recursão infinita:

- [Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74412/uncaught-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded)
- [erro Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/452661/erro-uncaught-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded)
- [Erro jQuery: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155416/erro-jquery-uncaught-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded)